# text to image rollover with fade in/out

Tags: jquery, rollovers

I have found and tinkered with a good way to create a text to image rollover, here: http://jsfiddle.net/pkZAW/12/

```
    $( function() {
  $("#imglink").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).attr('small',$(this).html());
      $(this).html($(this).attr('full'));
    },
    function () {
       $(this).html($(this).attr('small'));
    }
  );
});​
```

However, I need the transitions in and out to be faded, as it is on the thumbnail images here: 
http://lydiafraserward.co.uk/index.php?page=producing

After much searching around, I've not been able to add this transition to the script :-? .. any ideas..?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think live() is required for this situation. I wouldn't use fadeout on the mouseleave function because the animations will stack up.

You could also try this:

```
$( function() {
    $("#imglink").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).attr('small',$(this).html());
        $(this).stop(false,true).fadeOut(250,function() {
            $(this).html($(this).attr('full'));
            $(this).stop(false,true).fadeIn(250);
        });
   }, function () {
        $(this).html($(this).attr('small'));

   });
  });
```

Edit: the flicker effect is fixed using a span tag around the anchor tag: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LYjvp/1/

Comment: hey thanks for your reponses! It does seem to work, though the image appears to stay visible/flickers if one runs over it too quickly. Is there a way to definitively stop this? I altered the <a> tag to display:block as i'd like the text link to be the same size as the image, though this does not appear to have made a difference.. http://jsfiddle.net/9qeZv/33/

Comment: To fix this I think you need to wrap a span tag around it. See this DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/LYjvp/1/

Comment: Hi, i've been trying out the solution with the <span> added, but it still appears to break if the mouse runs over it too fast. Either the image gets stuck or both image and text disappear..

Comment: Yeah you are right, I think you should split the image and text to make it more solid. Test this fiddle and let me know what you think: http://jsfiddle.net/6A5UY/1/

Comment: Many thanks erwin_smit! That works smoothly now! However, is it possible to do this without using css positioning for the rollover? I need to put the rollover onto a page which uses jquery super slider (http://nicinabox.github.com/superslides/). Unfortunately the css positioning with the rollovers conflicts with the css positioning used by Super Slider. As a result, the rollover image jumps around a;; over the place if the screen is resized.. you can see what I mean here: http://lydiafraserward.co.uk/index.php?page=test